# How do I change the cursor type when using the Ubuntu app on Windows 10?

Tags: command-line, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am working on a Windows 10 machine. I have recently downloaded the [Ubuntu app](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBLGGH4MSV6) from the Windows Store for faster and better use of repo and git.  Is there a way to change the cursor in the Ubuntu terminal?  Right now it is the default block.  I would prefer the ibeam (vertical line) style that blinks, similar to what most word processing applications use.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBLGGH4MSV6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe Windows Subsystem for Linux supports changing the cursor in the default terminal. If you want to use a different cursor type, or a more advanced terminal, you need to replace it.

I believe that https://github.com/goreliu/wsl-terminal would be the easiest way of getting a new terminal for WSL. It runs mintty internally which does support a different cursor style. If you do not wish to install it, you should be able to install the mintty wsl terminal directly with https://github.com/mintty/wsltty

Comment: Thank you!  I may look into changing my terminal all together or simply living with the underline cursor style.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this article](https://medium.com/better-programming/make-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-10-look-like-the-ubuntu-terminal-f7566008c5c2), which helped me address my issues related to the appearance of Ubuntu terminal on Windows 10.

In your Ubuntu App's WSL terminal, go to the *Properties* item in the top left menu:

[image: Menu]

Select the *Terminal* tab, where you can set *Cursor Shape* and *Cursor Color*:

[image: Properties]